# Jquery width() is giving wrong value when calculating the text width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple text inside span. I just wanted to animate it from right to center of the `#maincontainer`.
Therefore i did a calculation to make it center horizontally. I tried with `outerWidth()` as well. It didn't work. Here is the code.

```
<span id="headline">Hi There! Say hello to world.</span>
```

`#maincontainer` width is 728m But `#headline` container is giving wrong calculation every time.

```
$("#headline").css({"top": (($("#maincontainer").height()-($("#headline").height()))/2)}).delay(1e3).animate({
    "right":  $("#maincontainer").width() - $("#headline").width() + "px"
},5e2);
```

Comment: any fiddle available??

Comment: may be simpler with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1/** `<span>` as an inline element, has no dimensions. Asking for them will return "undefined".

Tranform `<span>` to an inline-block element with CSS.

```
<span style="display:inline-block" id="headline">
```

Why inline-block and not block ? Because you want the width of the displayed text only, and not the width of a whole block (same as the container probably).

**2/** Also, `width()` or `style.width` will give a blank result if width has not been previously defined for the element.

In this case, use: `$("#headline").offsetWidth`

Answer (score 0):

`width()` and `height()` methods don't work on html elements who has `display:inline` style.span by default is with `display:inline`. to fetch width or height you can use `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.